# ElasticSearch: Atomic bulk update

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to do bulk atomic updates in ElasticSearch?

I am aware that regular bulk updates are not atomic as noted here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html#bulk

Is there any other way to atomically update multiple documents? i.e. Either all the updates happen or none of them do.

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch doesn't currently have a way to do what you're asking for. There are several responses to this question on the Elasticsearch site.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-es-support-transaction-such-as-rollback/12579

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/rollback-es-6/85958

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15316

Currently you would need to architect a solution yourself. There is an interesting blog about a potential solution here: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/10/transactions-elasticsearch/

Comment: Thanks for the links. Didn't find them when googling. Will take a look