# Is it possible to publish many events to ElasticSearch at once as a transaction? So if one publication fails, ES databse rolls back?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-beats

What I'm doing atm is: I gotta fetch a XML file from a server. This XML contains many logs and each log is parsed and turned into an event, a `beat.event`. What I want is, to send all logs to elasticsearch, or send none. Can I make a huge event and publish everything at once? Or make a queue to store all events that need to be sent, so that if one event fails to be sent the transaction is over and elasticsearch rolls back?

The word here is transaction. I want to publish all or nothing. Is there a way to achieve this?

My code below:

```
for i := 0; i < len(s.List); i++ {
                //fmt.Printf("Starting to build the event %v \n", i)
                event := beat.Event{
                    Timestamp: time.Now(),
                    Fields: common.MapStr{
                        "id":                s.List[i].Id,
                        "sipCallId":         s.List[i].SipCallId,
                        "originNumber":      s.List[i].OriginNumber,
                        "targetNumber":      s.List[i].TargetNumber,
                        "originDDD":         s.List[i].OriginDDD,
                        "targetDDD":         s.List[i].TargetDDD,
                        "originInstitution": s.List[i].OriginInstitution,
                        "targetInstitution": s.List[i].TargetInstitution,
                        "setupTime":         s.List[i].SetupTime.SetupTime,
                        "connectTime":       s.List[i].ConnectTime.ConnectTime,
                        "disconnectTime":    s.List[i].DisconnectTime.DisconnectTime,
                        "duration":          s.List[i].Duration,
                        "originType":        s.List[i].OriginType,
                        "targetType":        s.List[i].TargetType,
                        "answered":          s.List[i].Answered,
                        "callCompleted":     s.List[i].CallCompleted,
                        "sipJustification":  s.List[i].SipJustification,
                        //Dados adicionados como argumentos pra chamada do programa.
                        "tipoDoEquipamento":    bt.config.TipoEquipamento,
                        "versaoDoEquipamento":  bt.config.Versao,
                        "nivelDoEquipamento":   bt.config.Nivel,
                        "instituição":          bt.config.Instituicao,
                        "enderecoIP":           bt.config.Ip,
                        "timestampColeta":      time.Now(),
                        "consolidado":          bt.config.Consolidado,
                        "timestampConsolidado": bt.config.TimestampConsolidado,
                    },
                }
                bt.client.Publish(event)
                logp.Info("Event sent")
                //fmt.Printf("Event %v published \n", i)
```

Comment: This is not possible, elasticsearch [does not have transactions](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql#transactions).

Comment: Yes, this is not possible. You need to architect the solution yourself. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539822/elasticsearch-atomic-bulk-update